# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип. Существует явное преобразование

Tags: c#

> ```
> "(локальная переменная) Поезд с.  
> Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "EFCourseNew.Поезд" в  
> "System.Collections.Generic.lConnection<EFCourseNew.Поезд>". Существует явное 
> преобразование(возможно, пропущено приведение типов).
> ```

```
private void btnAddPassenger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Поезд c = поездBindingSource.Current as Поезд;
    if (c != null)
    {
        if (пассажирBindingSource.DataSource == null)
            пассажирBindingSource.DataSource = c.Пассажир.ToList();
        Пассажир a = new Пассажир() { Поезд = c };
    }
}
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Что такое `Пассажир`?

Comment: на какую именно строку ругается?

Comment: Использовать кириллицу в названии переменных - это очень, прям очень дурной тон

Comment: Этот код еще читался если бы вы хоть следовали своему правилу наименования во всем: вместо `Поезд c = поездBindingSource.Current` должно быть `Поезд поезд = поездBindingSource.Current` ну или  `Поезд п = поездBindingSource.Current`, а у коллекций должно быть множественное число тогда вместо `c.Пассажир.ToList();` было бы  `поезд.Пассажиры.ToList();` А по сути вопроса, надо увидеть классы ваших поездов и пассажиров чтобы понять в чем проблема.

Comment: @Grundy,  Ругается на строку "Пассажир a = new Пассажир(){Поезд = с}

Comment: @Igor, Работаю с Фрэймворком Entity, Поезд и Пассажир - это таблицы в базе данных SQL Server, понимаю что это дурной тон - использовать кириллицу, но уже создал такую базу данных

Comment: @Bulson, Поезд и Пассажир - это созданные при помощи фрэймворка Entity модели таблиц из базы данных SQL Server

Comment: @НикитаФилиппов "Ругается на строку ..." - я так и думал :). Посмотрите, какой тип у свойства `Пассажир.Поезд`.  Это не `Поезд`.